# Firebase Cloud Functions does not create document in a subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I use Firebase Cloud Functions in my Flutter app to create a document inside a collection it works:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
exports.onCreatePost = functions.firestore
    .document("/posts/{postId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const doc = snap.data()
        const creatorId = doc.creatorId
        admin.firestore().collection('feeds').doc(creatorId).set({ 
                  Id: creatorId, 
                  isRead: false, 
                  timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
            })
        });
```

But when I try to add the same document inside a subcollection in that document, it does not work:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 
exports.onCreatePost = functions.firestore
    .document("/posts/{postId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const doc = snap.data()
        const creatorId = doc.creatorId
        admin.firestore().collection('feeds').doc(creatorId).collection('feedItems').doc(context.params.postId).set({ 
                  Id: creatorId, 
                  isRead: false, 
                  timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
            })
        });
```

What am I doing wrong? I do see that the cloud function was completed successfully in the logs, but the docment is not created in my Cloud Firestore.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would expect neither function to work reliably, because you aren't returning a promise that resolves after the asynchronous work is complete.  If you don't return a promise, then Cloud Functions might terminate your function before it's done.

Minimally, you should return the promise returned by `set()`.

```
return admin.firestore()
  .collection('feeds')
  .doc(creatorId)
  .collection('feedItems')
  .doc(context.params.postId)
  .set(...)
```

You should also check the Cloud Functions log for errors.  Errors will not show up in your app since the code is running completely outside of it.

I suggest also [reviewing the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) on this.

Comment: I tried that too. but didn't work either.I understand that without return, it's not reliable, but it did work for only adding document to collection, not subcollection. I also did add a .then(()=> { return console.log('Write succeeded!');}); to the version with "return" and the cloud functions console does show the message "Write succeeded!".. but I don't see the document in cloud firestore. I do not see any errors in cloud function logs either

Comment: ah..I figured what was happening.. the document was being created, but because of another logic in mu Flutter code, it was being deleted right after. Thanks for the help though!